# I have an existing asp.net mvc site (on iis 7), can I add wordpress on a /blog subdirectory?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

I have an existing site that is using asp.net mvc 2.0 and I want to add wordpress in a /blog subdirectory.

Is this possible? How would I go around to doing this?

The site has a wildcard SSL certificate, not sure if that has any effect on the binding for the subdirectory?

Also, are there any security issues I should be worried about (besides for keeping wordpress up-to-date?)

Answer (score 1):

Since Wordpress runs on php, you probably need to setup the `/blog` subdirectory as the root of a separate php application. You'd do this in IIS, separate from all settings controlling your MVC application.

In the MVC app, you need to ignore the blog from the routes. Add the following at the top of your route registration:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("blog/{*pathInfo}");
```